# Export git repository with history into another repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have a repository called "A" that needs to be moved into repository "B" without loosing the history, this is as if it always was on "B".

Please note that I don't need to move a folder or a part of a repository, but the complete repository content into another one, basically renaming repository "A" to "B" without loosing "A".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why Not use simply git clone ? You always geht the complete history...,

Comment: The problem is that the remote repo is wiped, so I have a local copy of "A" that I wish to push into "B" without loosing the history.

Comment: Flupkear, have a look at @yuri's answer below, that's simple and works well.

Answer (score 3):

add the A as a remote on B. Do a `git fetch remote_A` in repo B and you will have imported the entire history.

Comment: The problem is that the local copy of "A" not longer represent the remote version, this is I have a local copy of "A" that will be completely wiped if I do a "git pull" so I want to save the  local "A" into another repo before is wiped, not sure if possible though.

Comment: This does not matter. When you do the fetch, all the branches will be preceded with "remate_A". Use them if you like. Git log --all will show them and you can grep for certain things. If you don't have anything in repo B, then a file copy will be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to get my head around it. If I understood you well, I have to do a clone of "B" in a new folder, copy "A" into "B" (without .git folder I presume) and just commit / push.

Comment: no. You need to copy the .git folder as well. That contains the history.

Answer (score 1):

Git repositories are just folders and you can copy A to B to "rename without losing" A.

Comment: I tried this, just copy "A" to "A-copy" then did git-init, git add-remote <repo>, git commit, git push but it failed. I edited .config on git and both repos are there, if I just remove the "A" definition and try again will work?

Comment: @Flupkear What is `git add-remote`? Give the exact steps and edit into your question

Comment: Sorry, I meant "git remote add", but this is irrelevant since it was just a test I did. If I understood well, just cloning the empty "B" repo into a folder and copy-paste "A" folder content into "B" will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy all the files, including the hidden .git directory, from DirA to DirB.

Then open DirB/.git/config and change the repo location from RemoteRepoA to where RemoteRepoB is.

Then from within DirB just do:

```
git push origin master
```

All the code with history should then be added to RemoteRepoB. I just did this with 2 repos on GitHub.

Comment: +1 I've managed to do the same - this looked the simplest method of all create/apply patch, etc. It worked for me, and all looks intact - I'm not sure though if it has any drawbacks.